# How to configure programs to automatically reopen after a GUI reboot?

Tags: unity, session

I am looking for a way that when I press CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE (which reboots the GUI and sends me to the login screen) and I enter my desktop again all my programs can autostart. For example Firefox will all the tabs I had before the GUI reboot, gedit opened with the tabs I had and any other program that was opened before I rebooted the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question used to be gnome-session-save but it is dead right now.  Hopefully they will come back to life eventually, but for the time being there is gno saved session in gnome-session.  Xfce and Kde still have save sessions I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Dash button. Type the word "startup" (minus quotes). Choose "Startup Applications". When it opens, click the "Add" button and choose your app. Repeat for each app you wish to start at login.

Comment: This is not reopening a previous closed app. This is setting what default apps should open when Ubuntu starts.